# Custom Attributes for POSIX Threads

Tags: c, pthreads

Is it possible to add a custom attribute (i.e. name, mutex block level, etc) to a POSIX thread? The idea is to manipulate information attached to a thread context.

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought of [thread-local storage](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/rzah4mst.htm) (TLS). But perhaps you want to do this from outside the thread ... if so, TLS won't work since it's only valid for code running inside the thread.

But since you have a unique identifier for all threads (the [threadid](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/rzah4mst.htm)) you should be able to use any dictionary-type data structure with that as the key.